# The variable from the function is not returned to the code and I get the error: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python, function, return

The variable from the function is not returned to the code.

Here is the Python code that causes the problem:

```
def test():
    a = 0
    return(a)
test()
print(a)
```

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: `print(test())` When you do just `test()` the esult of the function call is obtained and immediately lost after.

Comment: The function returned the *value* `0`, not the name `a`. [This might be helpful reading](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Comment: This isn't how `return` works. You aren't returning *a variable*, you always return some *object*. In this case, you didn't assign the return value to anything, so it simply gets discarded.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you said the function returns `0` and that's exactly what it should do, the way you're doing it isn't working because the definition of `a` is in the function and not in the global scope. You can either define `a` outside of the function or use `print(test())`

if you want to print the variable name you must consider the same thing for the scope but you can use:

```
variable_name = [k for k, v in locals().items() if v == 710][0] 
print("Your variable name is " + variable_name)
```

`variable_name` can also be returned in your function

Comment: You pretty much *never* need to know the name of a variable. If you think you do, you should be using an explicit dict to map the name to the value.

Comment: yep that's true, I just gave an option for the OP since in the comment under their post they said they did want  a return of `0`